# remove class from all elements but 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So i feel like the code I have should work but it doesn't. the intention is to remove the class editable from every element except a specific one.

```
$('*').not(gCms.section).removeClass("cmsEdit")
```

I have also tried doing

```
$('*').each().not(gCms.section).removeClass("cmsEdit")
```

I am sure I am making some dumb mistake somewhere but please help me out guys.

Edit: Sorry for not specifying guys. gCms.section is a string containing something along the lines of "#someID"

Comment: Why are you looking up every element? You should have `$(".cmsEdit").not(...`

Comment: gCms.section is a object ? Or you wanted to mean '#gCms.section' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always try and avoid the `$( "*" )` selector. It matches **every single** element on your page. That includes the `<body>` and `<head>` and...well...everything! IMO it really is overkill and I'm not too sure why it exists! I've never seen an instance where you can't avoid it.

Instead of trying to encompass this action into one command, you could always accomplish this task with some code similar to this:

```
// For any element containing the class cmsEdit, remove it.
$( ".cmsEdit" ).removeClass( "cmsEdit" );
// (Re)add the class to the element you want
$( other_element ).addClass( "cmsEdit" );
```

What you loose in "elegance" by performing a "one-liner" command, you gain in readability.

Comment: So i don't need a .each call? there are several elements that have the class cmsEdit but by the time it's over i need there to be only one.

Comment: Nope - you don't need an `each` command. The `$( ".cmsEdit" )` selector will match all the elements containing that class, so `removeClass()` will work on all of the matched elements; Short and sweet :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `$('*:not(#gCms.section)').removeClass("cmsEdit")`

And your `gCms.section` needs an identifier such as an `id` or `class` (pound == id, period == class).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't accidentally twisted them around, and that you actually meant this?

```
$("*").not("section.gCms").removeClass("cmsEdit");
```

Comment: entirely sure gCms is a global namespace for the javascript

Answer (score 0):

you can do this like this i think:

```
var element =  $("#gCms.section");
$('*').each().not(element).removeClass("cmsEdit");
```

It replace cmsEdit from all element but not from Id **gCms** => class section.